# Divide an array into two if it has more than 10 elements C#

Tags: c#

I get an array with some number of elements. When there are more than ten elements in the array, then I need to create a new array.

For example we have the collection:

`var list = var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};`

I expect such a result:

`list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

`list2 = {11, 12, 13}`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) and [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) as follow:

```
var list1 = list.Take(10).ToList();
var list2 = list.Skip(10).ToList();
```